# Jenkins Cron Expression Running Off Schedule

Tags: jenkins, cron

I configured a Jenkins job to trigger everyday at ~12am. However, I noticed that it's consistently running at ~4pm.

[image]

I'm running Jenkins in a Docker container and I set the system timezone in a script under `$JENKINS_HOME/init.groovy.d/` that does following:

```
System.setProperty('org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.fmt.timeZone', 'America/Vancouver')
```

**Question**: Any clue as to why it's not running according to my expected schedule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it's running the cron schedule according to the host container timezone, rather than what's set on Jenkins. Not sure why the UI is displaying the predicted schedule according to Jenkin's set timezone. I fixed it by adding the following to the image's Dockerfile:

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:2.176.1

.
.
.

# Switch to root user
USER root

# Install tzdata
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y tzdata

# Configure timezone to America/Vancouver (UTC-08:00)
RUN rm -f /etc/localtime \
&& ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Vancouver /etc/localtime \
&& dpkg-reconfigure --frontend noninteractive tzdata

.
.
.
```